# Queued jobs are somehow being cached with Laravel Horizon using Supervisor

Tags: laravel

I have a really strange thing happening with my application that I am really struggling to debug and was wondering if anyone had any ideas or similar experiences.

I have an application running on Laravel v5.8 which is using Horizon to run the queued jobs on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. I have a feature that archives an account which is passed off to the queue.

I noticed that it didn't seem to be working, despite working locally and having had the tests passing for the feature.

My last attempt to debug was me commenting out the entire `handle` method and added `Log::info('wtf?!');` to see if even that would work which it didn't, in fact, it was still trying to run the commented out code. I decided to restart supervisor and tried again. At last, I managed to get 'wtf?!' written to my logs.

I have since been unable to deploy my code without having to restart supervisor in order for it to recognise the 'new' code.

Does Horizon cache the jobs in any way? I can't see anything in the documentation.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Any ideas on how I can stop having to restart supervisor every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

> Remember, queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers.
>
> Alternatively, you may run the queue:listen command. When using the queue:listen command, you don't have to manually restart the worker after your code is changed; however, this command is not as efficient as queue:work:

And as stated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/horizon#deploying-horizon) in the Horizon documentation.

> If you are deploying Horizon to a live server, you should configure a process monitor to monitor the php artisan horizon command and restart it if it quits unexpectedly. When deploying fresh code to your server, you will need to instruct the master Horizon process to terminate so it can be restarted by your process monitor and receive your code changes

When you restart supervisor, you are basically restarting the command and loading the new code, your behaviour is exactly as expected to be.